# What if OP has doubts about the code being working?

Tags: discussion, site-policy

I was browsing questions and found [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29083/is-there-a-flaw-in-my-program). In this the OP states that the code is working according to him but someone told him that it isn't working.

What kind of review should be done in such situations?

Comment: Interesting.  That developer not elaborating on his evaluation is not helpful, either.  Beyond that, I _suppose_ it can be a compiler thing.  If two people are using different compilers or different versions of the same one, the results can look skewed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the question is essentially the same idea as this one:

[Calculate SHA1 hash from binary and verify with a provided hash](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/27824/what-is-wrong-with-my-code-the-recruiter-said-it-didnt-meet-their-bar)

I think the appropriate review would have been to point out the flaws in the code (as in the linked question). However, we don't know what the friend was talking about. I think we can give a generic review, even if we can't see what the friend saw.